Hawking and Ellis Lemma 4.3.1 Proof
I have a few questions about Hawking and Ellis' proof of this lemma (pages 92-93):

Write the $(2, 0)$ stress-energy tensor in coordinates as
$\mathbf{T} = T^{ab} \partial_a \otimes \partial_b$ and the differential of the $C^2$
function $t$ as $$dt = \frac{\partial t}{\partial x^a} dx^a.$$
Is the $T^{ab} t_{;a}$ term the components of the vector $\mathbf{T} (dt, -)$?

When Hawking writes the integral over the boundary $\partial \mathscr{U} (t)$ he says the second integral (the one over the region $\mathscr{U} (t) \cap (\partial \mathscr{U})_2$)
is non-negative. Is that because the integral picks up a negative sign due to the sign ($\pm 1$ depending on whether the boundary is timelike or spacelike) of the normal form, but the metric $\mathbf{g}$ is also negative because both vectors (specifically $\mathbf{T} (dt, -)$ and the normal vector $\mathbf{n}$) being put into $\mathbf{g}$ are causal (so the two negatives cancel resulting in a positive value)?

Where can I find a proof or further explanation for Hawking's line: "Since $\mathscr{U}$ is compact there will be some upper bound to the components of $t_{;ab}$ in any orthonormal basis whose timelike vector is in the direction of $t_{;a}$"?


